# Computing the change in bills and coins from two inputs

Tags: c, math, precision, integer-arithmetic

I have a school assignment to compute the change in bills and coins after providing two inputs which is the cost of the item and money tendered. In the instructions, there is a test case mentioned where it says

> Please include as a test a case in which the number of dollars, if multiplied by 100.0 and cast to int without the tiny amount added in, would be just short of the correct integer number of pennies.

I'm not sure exactly what it requires when it says would be just short of the correct integer number of pennies. 
If someone can explain, it will be really helpful.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  double dcost, dtendered;
  int    icost, itendered;
  int    itwenties, itens, ifives, iones, iquarters, idimes, inickels, ipennies;
  /* add any additional variables between here -> */
  int itotal;
  /* <- and here*/

  scanf("%lf", &dcost);
  scanf("%lf", &dtendered);

  icost     = (int)((dcost * 100.0) + 0.000001);
  itendered = (int)((dtendered * 100.0) + 0.000001);

  /* add code to calculate itwenties, itens, etc., between here -> */
  itotal    = itendered - icost;
  itwenties = itotal / 2000;
  itotal    = itotal % 2000;
  itens     = itotal / 1000;
  itotal    = itotal % 1000;
  ifives    = itotal / 500;
  itotal    = itotal % 500;
  iones     = itotal / 100;
  itotal    = itotal % 100;
  iquarters = itotal / 25;
  itotal    = itotal % 25;
  idimes    = itotal / 10;
  itotal    = itotal % 10;
  inickels  = itotal / 5;
  itotal    = itotal % 5;
  ipennies  = itotal;

  /* <- and here */

  printf("%2d twenties\n", itwenties);
  printf("%2d tens\n", itens);
  printf("%2d fives\n", ifives);
  printf("%2d ones\n", iones);
  printf("%2d quarters\n", iquarters);
  printf("%2d dimes\n", idimes);
  printf("%2d nickels\n", inickels);
  printf("%2d pennies\n", ipennies);

  while (1)
    getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

in line 23, 24 i have added that tiny amount

Edit : I am attaching the instruction sheet for this assignment on this link 
pls have a look once. https://docs.google.com/document/d/1RolSvpg5Purn4_IrhG1cbrrcSwHjYvnDcIZQ3uoQM8U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Please provide the quote of the assignment as text directly in the question. I.e. a link is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

The hint asks you to find an amount of whole dollars which results in one dollar less plus 99 cent when converted without the `+ 0.000001`.
I.e. you are probably meant to become aware of the imprecision problems of floating point math on a computer.

You do not need to do that in your program, on the contrary, you should convert correctly.

However you are supposed to have a test case which can detect if the code fails to use the tiny amount for correct conversion.

This means that if you hand in the basically correct program, it WILL be tested with such an amount. If that test (which might otherwise be considered an edge case) fails, then you have not only made a minor lapse, then you have not worked to explicitly stated requirements.
I imagine that would mean a bigger penalty to your grade...

Comment: Can you pls check once the instructions sheet I updated my post with

Comment: When I use 22.17 for cost and 99.99999999 for money tendered, when the tiny amount isn't added, in the output it shows 2 pennies, but when the tiny amount is added, in the output it shows 3 pennies. Is that what my instructions ask for? Thank you

Comment: Instructions guarantee correct input, i.e. nothing with more than two decimal places. So I am pretty confident that the test case you describe does not match the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're being asked to test what happens when `itendered < icost`. Perhaps ask your teacher to clarify!

Can you explain the logic behind `+ 0.000001)`? Do you know how floats are cast to ints? What is truncation?

Do you know why currency shouldn't be represented as a float? (Have you seen Office Space? Superman 2?)

Comment: Can you pls check once the instructions sheet I updated my post with